# DataAccessException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

Tags: mysql, jdbc, transactions, jooq

I'm having a method `addEvent()` which is adding event records from a webhook REST controller:

```java
public void addEvent(String subscriptionToken, DateTime eventTimestamp, SubscriptionEventType subscriptionEventType) {

    LOGGER.debug("Adding event: " + subscriptionEventType.name());

    this.ctx.transaction(configuration -> {

        // Transaction code ..

    });
}
```

The problem I am facing is that if two webhooks come in at the same time I am getting a `DataAccessException`:

```
[http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG com.mz.server.rest.braintree.webhooks.BraintreeWebhooksRestController - Webhook kind: SUBSCRIPTION_WENT_ACTIVE
[http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG com.mz.server.repository.jooq.payment.PaymentGatewaySubscriptionEventRepository - Adding event: WENT_ACTIVE
[http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG com.mz.server.spring.SpringTransactionProvider - ##### begin #####
[http-bio-8080-exec-6] INFO  com.mz.server.spring.SpringTransaction - SpringTransaction Ctor()
[http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG com.mz.server.rest.braintree.webhooks.BraintreeWebhooksRestController - Webhook kind: SUBSCRIPTION_CHARGED_SUCCESSFULLY
[http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG com.mz.server.repository.jooq.payment.PaymentGatewaySubscriptionEventRepository - Adding event: CHARGED_SUCCESSFULLY
[http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG com.mz.server.spring.SpringTransactionProvider - ##### begin #####
[http-bio-8080-exec-3] INFO  com.mz.server.spring.SpringTransaction - SpringTransaction Ctor()
[http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG com.mz.server.spring.SpringTransactionProvider - ##### commit #####
[http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG com.mz.server.spring.auth.CustomHttpSessionListener - Unhandled event
[http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG com.mz.server.spring.SpringTransactionProvider - ##### rollback #####
[http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR com.mz.server.rest.braintree.webhooks.BraintreeWebhooksRestController -
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [update `mz_db`.`payment_gateway_subscription` set `mz_db`.`payment_gateway_subscription`.`subscription_event_type_id` = ? where `mz_db`.`payment_gateway_subscription`.`id` = ?]; Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
    at org.jooq.impl.Utils.translate(Utils.java:1690)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.sqlException(DefaultExecuteContext.java:660)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:356)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractDelegatingQuery.execute(AbstractDelegatingQuery.java:133)
    at com.mz.server.repository.jooq.payment.PaymentGatewaySubscriptionEventRepository.lambda$0(PaymentGatewaySubscriptionEventRepository.java:73)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext$1.run(DefaultDSLContext.java:370)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext$1.run(DefaultDSLContext.java:367)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext.transactionResult(DefaultDSLContext.java:339)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext.transaction(DefaultDSLContext.java:367)
```

What can I do about that?

I don't understand why I'm getting this. It appears that the rows I'm accessing are getting locked and the next thread that comes in chokes on that. Is there a sane way to handle this issue? It's the first time I'm seeing this exception. Since this is the backend of a larger web application I'm not really looking forward to see something like that in production.. although at the moment I fear that this will happen if I do nothing about this.

Comment: From the current info that you've provided, it's not possible to assess what kinds of statements interfere with each other to produce a deadlock. In essence, there are (at least) two transactions that acquire locks in some order (perhaps reverse order) which causes them to wait indefinitely for the other transaction(s) to free the lock. You'll have to analyse all the other statements / transactions that are involved here at the same time.

Comment: @LukasEder Hi Lukas! :) I can provide the code inside the transaction if that helps. What I'm actually looking for is a solution that avoids such situations in all circumstances. I've seen that the common thing to do is make a retry with a certain delay but I'm not sure how I can do that. I'm using a Spring transaction manager in combination with jOOQ but I'm not sure if that's actually the right place. Any idea how I can do something like "repeat max. 4 times with a delay of 50ms" on a central place in my application?

Comment: *"I can provide the code inside the transaction if that helps"* - yes, of course. And also the code of the other transaction that is deadlocked. You always need at least two transactions for a deadlock. *"I've seen that the common thing to do is make a retry with a certain delay but I'm not sure how I can do that."* - Instead of gambling, you should avoid the problem in a deterministic manner. Think of Murphy's Law. It'll happen again if you work with delays.